# Spring Boot java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Tags: spring-boot

I Started a new project with Spring Boot 1.2.3. I'm getting error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
```

Gradle Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3")

    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    compile 'org.webjars:jquery:2.1.4'
    compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.4'
}
```

Here is the full stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 29 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you have `spring-boot-starter-web` in your dependencies?

Answer (score 185):

for the maven users,
comment the scope provided in the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE**

As feed.me mentioned you have to uncomment the provided part depending on what kind of app you are deploying.

Here is a useful link with the details: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: It's important to make this dependency "provided" again before building a war file! Otherwise the war file will crash when it gets deployed (happend to me with tomcat)

Comment: I also found I had to reimport the maven project in intellij, presumably to force the dependency to be downloaded with out this additional scope which was causing the application to prang out.

Comment: This is all well and good, the problem is that when you then build the war these jars are included and this is not an option.  Why can't IntelliJ figure out the proper classpath for running a Gradle + Spring Boot application?

Comment: I am faced with the same error in my spring security - I can see the javax.servlet-api in my libraries folder in IDEA but getting the above compiler error. Project downloaded from spring starter

Comment: Worked for me and was happening when trying to deploy using tradition war packaging method.

Comment: This method didn't work for me , I still getting an error :

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/GenericFilter

Comment: As you (@Dr.Agos) said in the UPDATE, depends on the app you are deploying, but how can I understand if I have to use scope provided or not? Can you please add an example for both possibilities? Thank you

Comment: Hey @Aerox, as far as I remember, when you were building a war, you need the provided scope, but if you're building a jar you don't need the scope field. 
Give it a try, cause this was a while back and in the past couple of years I haven't really used spring boot.

Answer (score 49):

It's not good to change the scope of your application dependencies. Putting the dependency as compile, will provide the dependency also in your artifact that will be installed somewere.
The best think to do is configure the RUN configuration of your sping boot application by [specifying as stated in documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html) :

> "Include dependencies with 'Provided' scope" "Enable this option to
>   add dependencies with the Provided scope to the runtime classpath."

[image]

Comment: Thats the solution. At least for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, It worked once i enabled "Add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath"

Comment: This an old thread, but nevertheless, it still helped us out of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have that checkbox, maybe because I'm on community edition?

Comment: can be because of the new version of Intellij.

Answer (score 37):

```
providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
```

This should be

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
```

Comment: Assuming that the error was at runtime, the `providedRuntime`'s limit was proper.  But the use of `providedRuntime` implies actually providing the `..-tomcat` code at runtime.  Perhaps, using `runtime` instead of `providedRuntime` could do that, without exposing the API that is not used at compile time.

Answer (score 29):

It's interesting things with IDE (IntelliJ in this case):

- if you leave default, i.e. **don't declare** *spring-boot-starter-tomcat* as **provided**, a *spring-boot-maven-plugin* (SBMP) put tomcat's jars to your war -> and you'll probably get errors deploying this war to container (there could be a versions conflict)
- else you'll get classpath with **no compile dependency** on *tomcat-embed* (SBMP will build executable war/jar with *provided deps* included anyway)
- - intelliJ honestly doesn't see *provided deps* at runtime (they are not in classpath) when you run its Spring Boot *run configuration* (since IJ 2020.3 *"include deps with provided scope"* option was added in run configuration).
- - and with no tomcat-embed you can't run Spring-Boot with embedded servlet container.

There is some tricky workaround: put Tomcat's jars to classpath of your idea-module via UI: `File->Project Structure->(Libraries or Modules/Dependencies tab)` .

- tomcat-embed-core
- tomcat-embed-el
- tomcat-embed-websocket
- tomcat-embed-logging-juli

### Better solution for `maven` case

Instead of adding module dependencies in Idea, it is better to declare maven profile with compile scope of *spring-boot-starter-tomcat* library.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>embed-tomcat</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

while `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` was declared *provided* in `<dependencies/>`, **making this profile active** in IDE or CLI (`mvn -Pembed-tomcat ...`) allow you to launch build with embedded tomcat.

Comment: your update solves the problem, **but** when you create a war file (production arctifact) you have to keep in mind that you have to activate the profile. which is not automatically done for you.

Comment: If your production artifact (PA) needs to be with embedded tomcat (ET) inside (in .war), it is not necessary to declare _spring-boot-starter-tomcat_ as _provided_ dependency. My answer explain the case when we need PA with **no** ET (as it had to be deployed on some container itself) and want to locally start `SpringBootApplication` **with** embed-tomcat in IntelliJ with its run-configurations.

Comment: I think the update is the correct solution for this problem in my opinion: you can build the war without embedded Tomcat and can use the profile inside IntelliJ. Very elegant and no commenting/uncommenting needed

Comment: in new version I see a checkbox, checking it will added provided dependencies at runtime for intellij !

Answer (score 17):

In my case scope of that dependency was `provided`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

So, I was getting the same issue.
*Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter*

I had to enable the below option in Intellij

`Add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath`

[image]

You will see below option enabled,

[image]

OR

You can add the below property to `.intellij/workspace.xml` file under your application configuration section.
`<option name="INCLUDE_PROVIDED_SCOPE" value="true" />`

e.g.,

````
  <component name="RunManager" selected="Application.DemoApp">
    <configuration name="DemoApp" type="Application" factoryName="Application">
      <option name="INCLUDE_PROVIDED_SCOPE" value="true" /> ```
````

Comment: Thanks mate for the solution. Have been banging my head for past 2 days on this.

Comment: Amazing, that was the actual issue in my case too. The project worked on STS but not on IntelliJ. Thanks again.

Answer (score 15):

Add the following dependency. The scope should be compile then it will work.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: ThQ so much it helps me :)

Comment: I just changed the scope from provided to compile and it works fine. Thanks much.

Answer (score 7):

For Jar

Add pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks - any idea why this was not autoadded?

Answer (score 3):

## 2023 Solution

Remove **provided** from maven of tomcat **artifactId**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <!--   Here <scope>provided</scope  >-->
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks like you tried to add the libraries `servlet.jar` or `servlet-api.jar` into your project `/lib/` folder, but Tomcat already should provide you with those libraries. Remove them from your project and classpath. Search for that anywhere in your project or classpath and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/provided-dependencies-with-spring-boot-the-war-plugin-and-intellij-idea/8761/8) is working for me:

```
configurations {
    customProvidedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        // Spring Boot dependencies
    )

    customProvidedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
}

war {
    classpath = files(configurations.runtime.minus(configurations.customProvidedRuntime))
}

springBoot {
    providedConfiguration = "customProvidedRuntime"
}
```

Comment: this worked for me but i had to remove the `springBoot` config. part

Answer (score 1):

Just comment the scope in spring boot dependency as shown below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
</dependency>
```