# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle

I am trying to write a standalone executable jar (fat jar) . I am using spring boot gradle plugin and writing a SpringBoot App to do this.

Here is my Application.java file

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableRabbit
@EntityScan("persistence.domain")
@EnableJpaRepositories("persistence.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"common","service"})
public class Application {

     public static void main(final String[] args) {
            final SpringApplicationBuilder appBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(
                Application.class);
            appBuilder.profiles("common", "common_db").run(args);
          }

      @Bean
      @Primary
      @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
      public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
      }
}
```

I have specified properties in yml files. For ex application-common etc . While running Application.java I am getting error :

```
[2015-09-24 14:40:22.304] boot - 32791  INFO [main] ---AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@51a282af: startup date [Thu Sep 24 14:40:22 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[2015-09-24 14:40:23.194] boot - 32791  WARN [main] --- AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:392)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:305)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
at storm.Application.main(Application.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:58)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:190)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:435)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:389)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:61)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
... 16 more
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
def projects= [
    ":common",
    ":persistence",
    ":adapter"

]

buildscript {
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}
dependencies { classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: springBootVersion }
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply from: "${rootDir}/deployTasks.gradle"

springBoot {
mainClass = "storm.Application"
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':adapter')
    compile project(':persistence')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.1.8.RELEASE'
    compile group : 'org.springframework.boot',name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version : '1.1.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.1.8.RELEASE'
```

}

Database specification as in application-common_db.yml

```
database:
host: localhost
port: 3306
schema: subscriptions
username: root
password: root
autoconnect:
maxReconnects: 3
initialTimeout: 2
timeout:
connectTimeout: 0
socketTimeout: 0
failover:
host: localhost 
port: 3306
queriesBeforeRetryMaster: 50
secondsBeforeRetryMaster: 30


spring:
datasource:
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://${database.host}:${database.port},${database.failover.host}:${database.failover.port}/${database.schema}?${database.properties}
username: ${database.username}
password: ${database.password}
continueOnError: true
initialize: false
initialSize: 0
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 5000
removeAbandonedTimeout: 60
removeAbandoned: true
minIdle: 0
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error . Can nybody suggest what is going wrong here and why am i getting nullPointerException.

Help is appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: This one helped me in resolving the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374316/spring-boot-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-filter

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**This is caused by non-matching Spring Boot dependencies.** Check your classpath to find the offending resources. You have explicitly included version *1.1.8.RELEASE*, but you have also included 3 other projects. Those likely contain different Spring Boot versions, leading to this error.

Comment: I checked the dependencies for all the projects included and all of them are using the same release (1.1.8.Release) . This didnt solve the problem for me :((((

Comment: Could you add a list of all the spring* jars from the fat-jar you are creating?

Comment: Gergely , if possible can u share your email address . I can share all the details there (my entire project structure and gradle files) . I will be very thankful to u.

Comment: I would rather not leave my e-mail address here. But you can put this list into your answer if you edit it.

Comment: What we need to compare is not just your explicitly defined dependencies (what you just posted), but the real jar files that are getting added to your jar file. This will include transitive dependencies as well, likely containing jars with offending versioning. Open your jar file and post a list of jars like: spring-data-jpa-1.1.8.jar, etc. I will be back in an hour btw.

Comment: Oh Gergely , it worked. When I saw list of referenced library , I could see jars for both 2.1.6 and 1.1.8 . Removing 2.1.6 from the path did the trick for me :) . Thankyou so much for assisting me here :) .

Appreciate it :)

Comment: Excellent. :) Happy to help.

Comment: Well, this is a long shot but could someone explain better how exactly you see the jar file and remove the offending version from the path?

Comment: @jimboweb It depends on what dependency managment system you use. If it is maven, then: opening the "effective pom" will show you the full list of dependencies. Search/grep whatever to find the offending resource. (or look at your lib folder if you are generating that). Removing it is done via exclusion tag in the dependency management section of your pom.

Comment: @GergelyBacso I'll try that. Thanks for answering; I don't often get a response on a 4 year old question.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite an old one, but I faced similar issue and resolved it in a different way. The actuator-autoconfigure pom somehow was invalid and so it was throwing IllegalStateException. I removed the actuator* dependencies from my maven repo and did a Maven update in eclipse, which then downloaded the correct/valid dependencies and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a new project, make sure you remembered to add spring starter web dependency

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of multiple projects having the offending resources.

Try out adding the dependencies projects another way around. (like in pom.xml or external dependencies)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had created a SB app from the SB Initializer and had included a fair number of deps in it to other things.  I went in and commented out the refs to them in the build.gradle file and so was left with:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
runtimeOnly 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb'
runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
```

as deps.  Then my bare-bones SB app was able to build and get running successfully.  As I go to try to do things that may need those commented-out libs I will add them back and see what breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same its because of hibernate-core version issue when you remove the version so it resolve the problem you should try it.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same its because of version incompatibility check for version or remove version if using spring boot