# BeanCreationException when creating an ElasticSearchRepository - Could not resolve matching constructor

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data

We have a spring boot application with maven. From today it started throwing the below error. There were few changes yesterday, we tried rolling back to a older version of code but still same error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:436)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:425)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at com.infy.mp.MarketplaceApp.main(MarketplaceApp.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationSearchRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:881)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:808)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:544)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:384)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration$DevToolsDataSourceCondition.getMatchOutcome(DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:133)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
... 21 common frames omitted

2016-12-16 12:26:26.519  WARN 7772 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4435f708: startup date [Fri Dec 16 12:26:18 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
at com.infy.mp.MarketplaceApp.main(MarketplaceApp.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

2016-12-16 12:26:26.520 ERROR 7772 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4435f708: startup date [Fri Dec 16 12:26:18 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
at com.infy.mp.MarketplaceApp.main(MarketplaceApp.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

Below is the ApplicationSearchRepository interface

```
package com.test.mp.search.repository;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import com.test.mp.domain.application.ApplicationElasticSearch;

public interface ApplicationSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ApplicationElasticSearch, String> {
public ApplicationElasticSearch findOneByJobIdAndPosterIdAndSeekerProfileId(String jobid, String posterid, String seekerprofileid);
```

I'm quite new to java, please let me know if you need any other info.

**Update**

The issue resolved after updating maven dependency versions of spring-data-* packages like below (non-working versions in comments).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <!--<version>1.13.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
        <version>1.13.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <!--<version>1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
        <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cql</artifactId>
        <!--<version>1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
        <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But now the integration tests continue to throw the same error. There are no spring-data related dependencies in test scope except cassandra-unit. Any clue why tests are failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As updated in the question **changing the maven version from BUILD-SNAPSHOT to milestone or release fixed the issue**. It seems when using BUILD-SNAPSHOT, the jar files get updated in the Maven respoitory whenever there is a new build. Which seem to be the reason why our application which was working one day stopped working the next day.

And for the **issue while running the tests** in eclipse, as suggested in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32761482/2742356) the **.classpath file** was referring to the BUILD-SNAPSHOT version of the jars. After removing those entries the tests also worked fine in eclipse.