# Multiple versions of spring boot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I am running a Spring app and getting the following error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketAutoConfiguration$TomcatWebSocketConfiguration.websocketContainerCustomizer`

A similar question has already been answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758000/java-lang-illegalstateexception-error-processing-condition-on-org-springframewo). In the accepted answer, Gergely Bacso states that the problem is multiple versions of Spring Boot.

The stack trace lists the error happening in `SpringBootCondition.java`, and when I try to click to it I am offered two different releases of Spring Boot, as seen in the image below:

[image: two versions of spring boot]

My questions are: 1) is this why I'm getting this exception? And 2) if so, how do I get rid of the extra version? (or alternately, if not, any other idea why this is happening?)

For reference, here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>murraco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwt-auth-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-jwt</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>taskorchard.JwtAuthServiceApp</start-class>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parentId from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- JPA Data (Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc..) -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Starter for using Spring Security -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Make method based security testing easier -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Automatically restart whenever files on the classpath change -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Automated JSON API documentation for API's built with Spring -->
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Generate beautiful documentation from a Swagger-compliant API. -->
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- JSON Web Token Support -->
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Model Mapper -->
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's my application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource: #TODO replace application.yml with an xml or java config file
    url: jdbc:${DBURL} #localhost/taskorchard
    username: ${DBUSER}
    password: ${DBPASSWORD}
  tomcat:
    max-wait: 20000
    max-active: 50
    max-idle: 20
    min-idle: 15
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false

server:
   port: 8080 # This is the default port anyway, but you can change it here

security:
  jwt:
    token:
      secret-key: secret-key
      expire-length: 300000 # 5 minutes duration by default: 5 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 miliseconds

UserController:
  signin: Authenticates user and returns its JWT token.
  signup: Creates user and returns its JWT token
  delete: Deletes specific user by username
  search: Returns specific user by username
  me: Returns current user's data
```

And when I run my maven dependency-tree I see this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/jimstewart/Git/ermine-defrock "-Dmaven.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf" "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50853:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.1.4 dependency:tree
objc[82632]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1029ef4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x102a734e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< murraco:jwt-auth-service >----------------------
[INFO] Building spring-boot-jwt 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ jwt-auth-service ---
[INFO] murraco:jwt-auth-service:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.196:runtime
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.6.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.357 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-19T21:34:36-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: SpringBoot 2.2.0 was juste release a few days ago, maybe there is something about that. But you don't seem to import other dependency that themselves depends on another SpringBoot version, weird

Comment: I see that SpringBoot 2.2.0 was added recently in my Project Structure-->modules. But when I try to take it out, Spring doesn't compile correctly at all, even when I take out any code I added since before I added it.

Comment: try changing `<version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>` to 2.2.0.RELEASE maybe ?

Comment: Usually you should never defined versions yourself which are inherited via Spring. Apart from that I can't reproduce with the given pom your problem...Have tried to build on plain command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I went to File-->Project structure, and saw `spring-boot-starter-test.2.2.0` in there. When I removed it, at first I didn't know what was going on because I had previously excluded the `log4j.logger-classic` module because of a different clash with a version of log4j, so when the program ran correctly I didn't see the log and didn't know it was running.

If you have a similar problem and can't figure it out comment on this and I'll try to help you.