# Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting the below error when I add the springboot jpa dependency and run.
Apart from that, I downgraded the jpa dependency version and tried, but still, it gives the same error.
(Here I have used a spring boot maven project and using java 8)

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pipi</groupId>
    <artifactId>myMicroServices</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myMicroServices</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring data jpa -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

console log:
Here is the console log, when I run the application.

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2020-03-16 14:28:11.773  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2020-03-16 14:28:12.988  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
2020-03-16 14:28:12.988  WARN 7688 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/default": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2020-03-16 14:28:12.991  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] com.pipi.MyMicroServicesApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-16 14:28:14.520  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-16 14:28:14.544  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-16 14:28:14.569 ERROR 7688 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.pipi.MyMicroServicesApplication.main(MyMicroServicesApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:743) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1688) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1604) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:223) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:213) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:167) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:142) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/hateoas/server/mvc/UriComponentsContributor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.UriComponentsContributor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    ... 54 common frames omitted

2020-03-16 14:28:14.573  WARN 7688 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.web.config.HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:743) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1688) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1604) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:613) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1242) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:869) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:857) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:844) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:795) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.pipi.MyMicroServicesApplication.main(MyMicroServicesApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/hateoas/server/mvc/UriComponentsContributor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.UriComponentsContributor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    ... 42 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758000/java-lang-illegalstateexception-error-processing-condition-on-org-springframewo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen when there are different incompatible versions of spring components. Please specify concrete (try to have the same) versions of all the spring dependencies.