# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

My app does not start because of a ClassNotFoundException error:
ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerFactory

I couldn't find anything like this online. For some reason it does not find this class.

My guess is that is has to do something with the dependencies. It could be some sort of conflict.

Below is build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.finstro'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    implementation 'org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.27.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign:3.1.2'
    implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.1.1'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-hystrix:11.8'
    implementation group: 'io.github.openfeign', name: 'feign-gson', version: '11.8'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix:2.2.10.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:1.5.18'
    implementation 'com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-javanica:1.5.18'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}


tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

application.yml file:

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql
    username: root
    password: password

  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
    default-schema: sys

  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:489)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at com.finstro.templatems.TemplateMsApplication.main(TemplateMsApplication.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:243)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/client/circuitbreaker/CircuitBreakerFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

From [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758000/java-lang-illegalstateexception-error-processing-condition-on-org-springframewo) :

> This is caused by non-matching Spring Boot dependencies. Check your classpath to find the offending resources. You have explicitly included version 1.1.8.RELEASE, but you have also included 3 other projects. Those likely contain different Spring Boot versions, leading to this error.

In your case, you've included two versions:

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
```

The referenced post also includes a comment linking to [Spring Boot java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374316/spring-boot-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-filter) that another user found helpful resolving this error.