# Why my spring-boot application is giving "ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter" in Intellij but not in STS 3?

Tags: spring-boot, exception, intellij-idea

While running my spring-boot application I'm getting this exception:

```
ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
```

I am getting this in case of **IntelliJ** only while it is running successfully in **STS 3**.

Is there any generic reason?

Comment: How does your pom.xml look like? And are you using a Servlet Filter?

Comment: use `mvn dependency:tree` and check the dependency is in the class path.

Comment: STS (or rather Eclipse) is notoriously bad in on honoring the scopes of dependencies from Maven/Gradle. So if something is provided/test it is visible in Eclipse, where it probably shouldn't be, and not in IntelliJ. So in short fix your dependencies to have the proper scope.

Comment: Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374316/spring-boot-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-filter Make sure to include the dependency that has `javax.servlet.Filter` class with `compile` scope. You can navigate to this class via Navigate | Class action, then check which jar lib does it come from.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I think there is no problem in pom.xml, since same application is running successfully on STS 3.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Should I look for jar containing `javax.servlet.Filter` class in that tree?