# Spring boot project not able to run on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a spring boot project, which I am able to run from command line. mean below two command are running fine.

```
 mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
 java -jar target/Data-Project.jar
```

I have import projects in IntelliJ like I am doing in other projects but in this project when I run it throwing below error.

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
```

The IntelliJ's configuration is correct as I have done many projects in IntelliJ. I have try lot of search and tried many things but its not working.

I  am stuck here, please get me out.

Comment: Could you please share your pom  file for furthur analysis

Comment: Could you show us your maven dependencies ? From pom.xml.

Comment: It sounds like this one : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374316/spring-boot-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-filter` but really need a view on your dependencies to confirm....

Comment: Hi @CodeScale The link you have given has the solution is worked for me. thanks. Now I understood the problem also.